# redmine bug when viewing in firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

There is an issue when viewing redmine project window in firefox. A project that contain subprojects gets split into columns.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoe5h.jpg

When opening in chrome it looks normal. Haven't tried any other browsers.

The html of this element:

```
<li class=root>
    <div class="root">
        <a class="project root parent public " href="/repositories/projects/p1">Project 1</a>
        <div class="wiki description"><p>Project 1 description</p></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="projects ">
        <li class="child">
            <div class="child">
                <a class="project child leaf public " href="/repositories/projects/p1.1">Project 1.1</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="child">
            <div class="child">
                <a class="project child leaf public " href="/repositories/projects/p1.2">Project 1.2</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="child">
            <div class="child">
                <a class="project child leaf public " href="/repositories/projects/p1.3">Project 1.3</a>
                <div class="wiki description"><p>Project 1.3 description.</p>
                </div>
           </div>
        </li>
        <li class="child">
            <div class="child">
                <a class="project child leaf public " href="/repositories/projects/p1.4">Project 1.4</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to figure out if this is a firefox bug or is there something wrong with the html.

Edit: this is a fragment of the css file, that i think is relevant:

```
ul.projects {margin:0; padding-left:1em;}
ul.projects ul {padding-left:1.6em;}
ul.projects.root {margin:0; padding:0;}
ul.projects li.root, ul.projects li.child {list-style-type:none;}
ul.projects div.description li {list-style-type:initial;}

#projects-index {
  column-count: auto;
  column-width: 400px;
  -webkit-column-count: auto;
  -webkit-column-width: 400px;
  -webkit-column-gap : 0.5rem;
  -moz-column-count: auto;
  -moz-column-width: 400px;
  -moz-column-gap : 0.5rem;
}
#projects-index li.root ul.projects { border-left: 3px solid #e0e0e0; padding-left:1em;}
#projects-index ul.projects li.root {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-break-inside: avoid-column;
  -moz-break-inside: avoid-column;
  page-break-inside:avoid;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
  width: 100%;
}
#projects-index ul.projects li.child {margin-top: 1em;}
#projects-index ul.projects div.root a.project { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; margin: 0 0 10px 0; }
#projects-index ul.projects div.description {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
```

Comment: HTML seems fine.

Comment: For display errors we need to have CSS that goes with the HTML:

Comment: I'll include the fragment of css that contains the word root.